# FCM push notification with angular service worker not does not receive

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement fcm cloud-messaging in my angular project, I managed to register the token and ask for notification permission.
But I am not receiving the messages.

firebase-messaging-sw

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app-compat.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js");

firebase.initializeApp({
 apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXX",
 authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
 databaseURL: "https://XXXXXXXXXX.firebaseio.com",
 projectId: "XXXXXXXXXX",
 storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com",
 messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXX",
 appId: "XXXXXXXXXX",
  measurementId: "G-XXXXXXXXXX"
});
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
console.log("service worker", messaging);
```

ANGULAR.JSON

"assets": [
"src/favicon.ico",
"src/assets",
"src/firebase-messaging-sw.js",
"src/manifest.json"
],

app.module

```
initializeApp(environment.firebase);
```

component

```
  requestPermission() {
    const messaging = getMessaging();
    getToken(messaging, 
     { vapidKey: environment.firebase.vapidKey}).then(
       (currentToken) => {
         if (currentToken) {
           console.log("token");
           console.log(currentToken);
         } else {
           console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
         }
     }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
    });
  }
  listen() {
    console.log("listen start");
    const messaging = getMessaging();
    onMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
      console.log('Message received. ', payload);
    });
    
  }
```

CALL INSOMNIA (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send)

```
{

    "notification" : {
        "title" : "test",
        "body": "test"
    },
    "to":"xxxxxx"
}
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Could you confirm that your FCM service worker is registered in your browser? (for ex: If you run in localhost:4200, start inspect -> Application -> Service Worker)

If it is registered, then check with your FCM configuration.

else try to use namespaced imports in your firebase-messaging.js

Please let me know it resolves your issue! Thanks!!

Comment: it is registered yes, I believe it is a silly error. i am testing the messages via cloudmessage test page and also tried with postman

Comment: @viniciuslucas06 dude I faced the same problem, where I managed to fix it by using namespaced imports and I made a typo with the naming of firebase-message.js instead of firebase-messaging.js. Also make sure that your manifest.json and firebase-messaging.js files are adjacent with index.html file.